# Given a json array, how do I extract a list of key values by key, using jq?

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have a json array that looks like this:

```
{
  "StackSummaries": [
    {
      "CreationTime": "2016-06-01T22:22:49.890Z",
      "StackName": "foo-control-eu-west-1",
      "StackStatus": "UPDATE_COMPLETE",
      "LastUpdatedTime": "2016-06-01T22:47:58.433Z"
    },
    {
      "CreationTime": "2016-04-13T11:22:04.250Z",
      "StackName": "foo-bar-testing",
      "StackStatus": "UPDATE_COMPLETE",
      "LastUpdatedTime": "2016-04-26T16:17:07.570Z"
    },
    {
      "CreationTime": "2016-04-10T01:09:49.428Z",
      "StackName": "foo-ldap-eu-west-1",
      "StackStatus": "UPDATE_COMPLETE",
      "LastUpdatedTime": "2016-04-17T13:44:04.758Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am looking to create text output that looks like this:

```
foo-control-eu-west-1
foo-bar-testing
foo-ldap-eu-west-1
```

Is jq able to do this? Specifically, what would the jq command line be that would select each StackName in the array and output each key one per line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jq --raw-output '.StackSummaries[].StackName'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ jq -r '[.StackSummaries[] | .StackName] | unique[]' input.json
foo-bar-testing
foo-control-eu-west-1
foo-ldap-eu-west-1
```

The -r option strips the quotation marks from the output.  You might not want the call to 'unique'.

For reference, if you wanted all the key names:

```
$ jq '[.StackSummaries[] | keys[]] | unique' input.json
[
  "CreationTime",
  "LastUpdatedTime",
  "StackName",
  "StackStatus"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution

```
jq -M -r '..|.StackName?|values' input.json
```